# OnClick Function in AJAX not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am relativly new to AJAX so please bear with me. I am able to get some data from my route and create a table using AJAX. With the data I have a button on each row that I want to use to make a POST and add some data to an array. The problem is, during testing the onclick function doesn't seem to be recognized. The function is recognized if I put it outside of the jQuery window, but I want to use the onclick to grab an ID and do a POST with it.

Here is my code:

```js
(function ($) {
    // HTML grabs
    let reqTable = $('#request-table');
    let req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/requests/requestId',
        //contentType: "application/json",
    };

    $.ajax(req).then((res) => {
        let requestText;

        let ownerId;
        let dogId;

        for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            requestText = res[i].requestText;
            ownerId = res[i].ownerId;
            dogId = res[i].dogId;

            reqTable.append(`<tr >
            <td><a href="../owners/${ownerId}">Owner Profile</a></td>
            <td>${requestText}</td>
            <td><button  onclick="btnClick('${ownerId}')">Accept</button>
            </td>
            
        </tr>`);
        }
    });
    function btnClick(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

This is my first question here so I am sorry if the format is incorrect. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The btnClick function doesn't have to be inside your IIFE to read the ID though.

Comment: Here's how I'd solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/p0achg8j/

Comment: `onclick="btnClick` `(function { function btnOnclick` - your btnOnclick is *scoped* to the IIFE so is not a global function.  `onclick=` has have to a global function.  In the code provided, there's no reason the btnOnclick function could not be defined outside the IIFE - there may be a reason in your "real" code, but that's unclear here.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript every function creates new scope. You can move btnClick function outside the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression - function that runs as soon as it is defined). In your case the IIFE is:

```
(function ($) {  })(window.jQuery);
```

Even better will be to bind the event using jquery after the new elements were appended to the DOM. Also more optoimized is to build the entire html and then append it to the DOM.

```
(function ($) {
// HTML grabs
let reqTable = $('#request-table');
let req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/requests/requestId',
    //contentType: "application/json",
};

$.ajax(req).then((res) => {
    let requestText;

    let ownerId;
    let dogId;
    let html = '';

    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        requestText = res[i].requestText;
        ownerId = res[i].ownerId;
        dogId = res[i].dogId;

        html += (
        `<tr >
            <td><a href="../owners/${ownerId}">Owner Profile</a></td>
            <td>${requestText}</td>
            <td><button class="accept-btn" data-owner-id="${ownerId}">Accept</button>
            </td>
        </tr>`
        );
    }
    reqTable.append(html).find('.accept-btn').on('click', function () {
       console.log($(this).data('owner-id'))
    });
});
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried the code you typed above but the console log was undefined instead of logging the ownerID

Comment: Should be `console.log($(this).data('owner-id'))` I guess

Comment: Sorry, fixed it :)